# What things are missable in disc 1 of Final Fantasy 7?

Tags: final-fantasy-7

We all know that a certain event happens at the end of disc 1 - but what things should I do before that event that won't be available after?

I can think of the following so far:

- all her limit breaks
- all her weapons
- maybe max stats(?)

Comment: I find your concern for not spoiling the event that happens in FF7 that everyone knows about heartwarming. You're a hero good sir. +1.

Comment: @MarkTrapp I would assume that "complete game" means unlocking and discovering everything.

Comment: @MarkTrapp Yes, and he's asking what he needs to do before that to ensure his game is complete - in other words, is their anything that if he does not do it before the end of disc 1, he will not be able to do it later.

Comment: @Chris based on your comment on my (now deleted because it's irrelevant after clarification) answer, I've edited your question to clarify what it is your looking for.

Comment: By complete I simply mean 'seeing' everything there is to see, and 'getting' everything there is to get. If I don't get her limit breaks/weapons on disc 1, I have no way of seeing them later. I was wandering if there was anything like this

Comment: @Mark Trapp: I find that title misleading, it sounds more like the question for a complete list (items, events, easter eggs etc.) instead of just things for one character. Though, I can't come up with a better one right now either.

Comment: I could mention a specific character, but it would be spoiler (regardless the age of the game)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't think there's much more you can do for her once you have her ultimate weapon and final limit break.

As for other missable items/materia, there's a [guide on GameFAQs](http://www.gamefaqs.com/ps/197341-final-fantasy-vii/faqs/27656) that details them.

Answer (score 2):

Get her to level 100 and obtain all her limit breaks and weapons, then move on. Accessories, materia and other similar collectibles aren't character related, so you can collect them later. I think the other characters' limit breaks and ultimate weapons won't be available on the first disc, so you can't use her as part of a fully maxed out team.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I was wandering if there was anything else a top of limits/weapons but that looks like thats it.

Comment: You can get Omnislash, All Creation, and Cosmo Memory on Disc 1.